# Как можно передать данные в firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, firebase

У меня есть проблема: я не знаю как передать данные(сейчас приведу проблем чтоб было легче объяснить)

```
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int a;
            Workout workout = products.get(position);


            if(workout.getT().equals("Amrap")){
                Intent intent= new Intent(wods.this, Amrap_wod.class);
                intent.putExtra("list",position );
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(workout.getT().equals("For-timer")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(wods.this, CapTimerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Workout- это мой класс для БД

Т.е у меня есть БД и в ней находятся разные тренировки. Я хочу чтоб при клике на ListView(lvMain), меня отправляло на след активности и на ней отображались все упраж из этой тренировки, как это сделать?)
(Я начинающий программист так что я даже не знаю как описать эту проблему в гугле)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно что вам нужно передать, если вы хотите передать целый класс посмотрите интерфейс Serializable,

```
  chat: Chat  
    args.putSerializable(ID_CHAT, chat)
```

через intent так тоже можно

```
chat = arguments?.getSerializable(ID_CHAT) as Chat
```

А потом перевести в свой объект

```
data class Chat(
    val messages: String = "",
    var last_message: Message? = null,
    var readNow: Boolean = false
):Serializable
```